# how to print data from object return by the database as object list?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, object, collections

i am trying to get data in spring mvc, my database has 2 row. so my database return two object as list but i want to specific value from returned object

this how i get the data and result

```
SQLQuery query1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM cart");
```

this how i print the list

```
System.out.println(query1.list());
```

i get result of `System.out.println(query1.list());`

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@16b2af1c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6e34df0e]
```

but i want specific value of object.
how to get the value of object return from database as list??

please help.....

Comment: Do you know how hibernate works? If not you should start here: https://hibernate.org/orm/

Comment: When you execute the query, you get a result set. you need to iterate over this result set to get individual entry.

Comment: You should iterate the result by a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query1.list();
```

Will give you a `Object[]`. You may want to create a object (in your case looks like a "Cart") to be able to desserialize and manipulate it better.

So now that you have a `Cart` object, you can do this:

```
List<Cart> cartList = Arrays.asList(query1.list());
```

Now you have a list of `Cart` and can do whatever you want to.

Like printing all `Cart` names:

```
for (Cart cart : cartList)
    System.println(cart.getName());
```

If that doesn't work, you can simply work with the `Object[]`:

```
List<Object[]> cartList = query1.list();
for(Object[] cart : cartList)
    System.out.println(cart[0].toString());
```

Comment: i get error like **[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.infotech.model.Cart**

Comment: Ok, it's because it's returning a Object[], not a List<Object>. Try doing this: Arrays.asList(query1.list())

Comment: or: 
List<Object[]> cartList = query1.list();
for(Object[] cart : cartList)
    System.out.println(cart[0].toString());

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like :

```
List<Cart> results = query1.list(); // list returns a List<T>

for (Cart cart : results){  // Which you iterate 
      System.out.println(cart.getItems());
      System.out.println(cart.getTotalPrice());
}
```

Comment: i get error **[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.infotech.model.Cart**

Comment: @DhruvRajkotiya can you try 
```List<Cart> results = (List<Cart>)(List<?>) query1.list();``` instead of  ```List<Cart> results = query1.list();```

Answer (score 0):

`List.toString()` relies on the `toString()` method of the elements of the List.
Seeing the result `[Ljava.lang.Object;@16b2af1c,...`, the class of the elements don't override `toString()`.

So as you guess to perform that kind of debugging output, you need to override `toString()` in the entity class which you have a list of.
Note that has to be done carefully with Hibernate because of fields referencing other entities that may provoke their initialization and so some other undesirable SQL requests could be executed.